# Display all tests run in a test class without -X option

Tags: maven, junit, surefire

Is there any way to configure the `mvn` command to display which tests (test methods within a test class) were run in the test summary (in the `Results:` section) without using the overly verbose -X option?

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.myproject.MyTestClass
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.033 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :
  #I would like to show the passed test here
Failed tests: 
  testTwo(com.myproject.MyTestClass)

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not easily. `maven-surefire-plugin`, which runs the tests, can only produce the summary and list of failed tests that you already see ([`DefaultReporterFactory#runCompleted`](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/9ef1843ba4851b82b5c8eb8271ad352690be0cc9/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/report/DefaultReporterFactory.java#L103)).

If you really wanted to add it to the build, you could process the XML files left in `target/surefire-reports` after the tests have run, perhaps using a Groovy script or something like [XSLT to standard output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575283/ant-xslt-task-output-to-stdout).